# How to exclude comma(,) in the output

Tags: awk

How to exclude "," from the below output while printing.

```
[root@test ~]# echo "list joblog job=host1"|bconsole| awk -F"|" '/host1/ {print $3,$6,$8}'

 host1   I          417,680,874
 host1   I       18,466,159,904
 host1   I        8,040,571,252
[root@test ~]#
```

Since "," is not a field separator in my requirement, not able to find the possible way to print the output like below:

Expected output -:

```
 host1   I          417680874
 host1   I       18466159904
 host1   I        8040571252
```

Request you to provide an help here.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk replace

```
print $3,$6,$8
```

with

```
gsub(",","",$8); print $3,$6,$8
```

to replace all `,` in $8 with nothing.

Comment: Why not simply `print $3, $6, gensub(",", "", "g", $8)` ?

Comment: @mathguy: There are certainly several ways to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Agreed; I meant, specifically, if you are going to use a `sub` function, why not use one that returns the value you need, rather than one that has the value you need as a side effect? It's the same solution, just written more simply.

Comment: @mathguy using `gensub()` would make the script only work in gawk (and some later versions of mawk) and so less portable. The script as written would work in any awk.